# Docker container for application binaries only

Tags: java, docker

I'd like to have each app release stored as some kind of container and then have several "server" only containers(DB, web server). How can the cooperation between those containers work?

I can imagine to define some volume in "app" container where the app. binaries will be stored and then use this volume folder as web server's deploy directory in the "server" container.

How will the process to update the application version work? How can I "bind" multiple binaries with one "server" container?

More generally I can imagine to deploy like this
"deploy some-version-releasecontainer to serv1, serv2, serv3", maybe docker is not the proper tooling and I will need some more abstract management like Swarm, kubernate etc. But the main point is to create application binary as **selfstanding, read-only entity** known to the eco-system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a docker-compose to make your containers interact on a virtual network (but you can still share resources and volumes). I'll post a simple example here.

The docker-compose is the following:

```
version: '2'

services:

  myapp_service1:
    image: myapp_image1:latest
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - myalias1
    depends_on:
     - mysql        
    expose:
     - 8080
    volumes:
      - /opt/myapp/logs:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/logs        
    environment:
     - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
     - "db=mysql.myapp"
    volumes_from:
      - myapp_volume  

  myapp_service2:
    image: myapp_image2:latest
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - myalias2
    depends_on:
     - mysql        
    expose:
     - 8080
    volumes:
      - /opt/myapp/logs:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/logs        
    environment:
     - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
     - "db=mysql.myapp"
    volumes_from:
      - myapp_volume  

  myapp_volume:
    container_name: myapp_volume
    image: myapp_volume_image:latest


  mysql:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - mysql.myapp    
    expose:
     - 3306
    ports:
     - "13306:3306"
    volumes:
     - /opt/myapp/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Here we have four containers. The first two are sample applications sharing the same volume. The volume is defined just below the applications and in the end we have a container which runs a simple MySql DB.

The Dockerfile for the shared volume container is that one:

```
FROM alpine

VOLUME /jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/mydir/config

CMD /bin/sh -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"
```

The docker compose is a yml file, let's say my-docker-compose.yml. To run it you have to type this in the terminal:

> docker-compose -f path/to/compose/my-docker-compose.yml up -d

Of course, the images should already be built.

Comment: myapp_volume_image contains some deployable? I need to run compose yml again when I want to update the app? How can I run multiple apps, I suppose I have to extend the volumes_from section, right?Docker-compose seems to just bundle the environment, ther is nothing dynamic in it.I.e. you can not add dynamically volumes-from to enable the server to run another application.